# Gibbons-Hawking space over over two points is $\text{T}^\ast\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is there any direct way of seeing that the space obtained via the Gibbons-Hawking ansatz over $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{p_1,p_2\}$ with a suitable choice of complex structure is biholomorphic to $\text{T}^\ast\mathbb{CP}^1$? I am aware that this result is implied by Kronheimer's classification of ALE spaces but [these notes](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/neitzke/teaching/392C-higgs-bundles/higgs-bundles.pdf) (Example 3.14, Exercise 3.16) seem to imply there is a more direct way of proving this, which I fail to see.

Originally, I have posted a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386450/gibbons-hawking-space-is-resolution-of-mathbbc2-mathbbz-k) on math stackexchange but it did not get any replies.